# Facebook share, change image

Tags: facebook

We recently finished building a website whereby we have a page where the user can make up a flavor by combining two ingredients, this then returns an image with both chosen ingredients working perfectly.

We then have a face book share button at the bottom of the page when the user presses this I want to pass the image that has been generated by the two ingredients the user has chosen and also add some additional text i.e pre-populate the status saying "Hey look at the flavor I just made" or something similar.

We currently have this set up

```
<div class="row col-lg-12 text-center danoneBlue">
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.domain.com.au/flavour-lab" data-layout="button"></div>
</div> 

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<meta name='og:image' content='~/Content/Images/HomeImages/MobileImages/MyDefaultImage.png' id="flavorCombinationImage">
```

this is the script tag

```
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I'm aware Facebook uses open graph meta tags. so I have placed a default image in there to see if it works, but when I run it I get a completly different one, i.e the one that was shown before.

What am I doing wrong here?

** Update **

I've place the following in my head section of the page

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Im the new title" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="Check out the flavour I have just created!" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="~/Content/Images/FlavourLab/danone_ultimate_black_cherries.png" />
```

but still no luck

Comment: What is the real url you trying to share?

Comment: @WizKid Sorry its "http://www.danoneultimate.com.au/flavour-lab

Comment: @WizKid I've just added a update to the question, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are no og-tags at all on http://www.danoneultimate.com.au/flavour-lab

Comment: @WizKid That's live, sorry the staging server is this one, http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/flavour-lab I'm able to change the title and description, it says for the image Object at URL 'http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/flavour-lab' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '/Content/Images/FlavourLab/danone_ultimate_black_cherries.png' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Comment: You should give an absolute URL for `og:image`.

Comment: @CBroe Ok I've done that but when I use this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and enter http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/flavour-lab at the bottom is display an incorrect image in the section "When shared, this is what will be included"

Comment: Stop ignoring the warnings the debug tool shows. (Re-scrape in case it should not show any for you yet.)

Comment: The warning say "and use an image that's at least 200x200px". Did you even read the warning?

Comment: @CBroe I'm not ignoring the warning I noticed this warning after my last comment. It says use an image at least 200x200px which I understand but It now references an image thats 260x222px if you re-run the debug tool you will see.

Comment: @CBroe I have made a 200x200px image which is http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/Content/Images/testImage.png when I run the facebook debug scrap tool it display's the image and shows how my post will look when shared which is what I want, yet when I actually go the site and click share it displays incorrect data and I get the warning The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.  The only other title I have on my page is the title for the application

Comment: Well then do what the warning says – provide an `og:url` meta element as well … As for it still sharing “incorrect data”, that is likely just a caching issue. After you added an `og:url` and refreshed the scraper info, clear your browser cache as well.

Comment: @CBroe I've given it a URL, cleared the cache on all three browser IE,Chrome and Firefox yet I still get the old image, now I have had problems with my PC would you be able to check your end and let me know? danoneultimate.com.au/flavour-lab you should have an image which a black background with black cherries.